# Calculate Median with Some Adjustments In Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, median

I have a data set in the following format and would to calculate the median but with some adjustments.

The raw data:

| Date | Item | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 3 |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 | C | 1 |
| 2021-02-01 | A | 6 |
| 2021-02-01 | B | 4 |
| 2021-03-01 | A | 8 |

Using "df_median = df.groupby(['Date']).median()", I can have :

| Date | Item | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 3 |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 | C | 1 |
| 2021-02-01 | A | 6 |
| 2021-02-01 | B | 4 |
| 2021-03-01 | A | 8 |
| 2021-01-01 | Meidan | 2 |
| 2021-02-01 | Meidan | 5 |
| 2021-03-01 | Meidan | 8 |

However, the above method would ignore the missing items. I would like to assign 0 values to the missing data when calculating the median (and only in the calculation). For example, when calculating the median for 2021-02-01, I would like to assign 0 to item C so that the median would be 4 instead of 5.

This is what I want to have:

| Date | Item | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 3 |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 | C | 1 |
| 2021-02-01 | A | 6 |
| 2021-02-01 | B | 4 |
| 2021-03-01 | A | 8 |
| 2021-01-01 | Meidan | 2 |
| 2021-02-01 | Meidan | 4 |
| 2021-03-01 | Meidan | 0 |

Comment: you are trying to get the result by median but desired result is different. because if you take the first date ie. 2,4,6 so median will be 4 and if you take the second date ie. only 6,4 here the median is like average that is 6+4/2 = 5 so the median is 5 and the last date is only 8, here median will be self number. so 8. you are right in by median but you just take another technique to get your desired result.

Comment: But why didn't you add item C which contains null value in 02-01-2021 to the main table?

Comment: @Hamzah Thank you so much for your reply! I overcomplicated it. Can obtain the result I want now.